# How to make a function which takes 5 and return 9, and takes 9 and return 5 without any logical and conditional operators like if-else and TO

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, conditional-statements, logical-operators

I have tried this but I thought switch is also a conditional statement

```
    function cal(n){
      switch(n){
      case 5: 
        return 9;
        break;
      case 9:
        return 5;
        break;
     }
    }
```

Comment: Look into arithmetic operators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with [bitwise XOR `^`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_XOR)

```js
function fn(n) {
  return n ^ 0b1100;
}

console.log(fn(5));
console.log(fn(9));
```

| a | b | a XOR b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |

The number 5 in decimal is 101 in binary, which means that

```
     101 
XOR 1101
--------
    1001 = (9 decimal)
```

The number 9 in decimal is 1001 in binary, which means that

```
    1001 
XOR 1101
--------
    0101 = (5 decimal)
```

`0b1100` itself is just a numeric literal expressed in binary. It is equal to 12 in decimal, so `n ^ 12` will work exactly the same way.

Comment: Very cool. Generally, any two numbers `a` and `b` can be switched between like this with the formula `f(n) = n ^ (a ^ b)`

Comment: No need to get that complicated, `f = n => 14 - n` :-)

Comment: @HolgerL that's actually good. I wasn't sure of the formula, I just "eyeballed" the 1101. Feel free to post an answer of your own. Or this information can be added to mine, if you prefer.

Comment: @Bergi or `({5: 9, 9: 5})[n]` :P Just felt like exposing XOR a bit more.

Comment: let's make it more simple to put simple arithmetic operations like 

fun(n){ 
return 45/n 
}

Comment: i would still consider `xor` to be logical..